# Plot Multiple Points Simultaneously

Tags: matlab

Let me start by saying that I suspect this is a very simple solution that I am somehow barely missing.

I'm trying to write a script that will plot one set of data in four separate subplots (each showing a different view of a 3D shape the points are being plot in), but I only want to show the current points - as in, I don't want to see *every* point, just one set of points as they progresses with time (I'm capturing video of the plot to visualize movement with time). However, for every instant in time, there are *n* points to plot simultaneously. I know this should be simple, but I can't manage to get all *n* points to plot at once - I can only seem to get it to plot one point at a time, which is pretty meaningless when you have *n* markers moving with time, all of which you'd like to see moving at the same time.

The following code works to plot every point in sequence, but does not plot all *n* points together, refreshing those points for every *t*:

```
n = 0;
for i = 1:length(data)
% every marker occurs in one row of a specific set of data, and is split
% into x, y, z, so I correct here for each marker being every 3rd column
    for j = 1:(cind/3) % cycle through every marker
        x = markerLoc(i, j*3 - 2);
        y = markerLoc(i, j*3 - 1);
        z = markerLoc(i, j*3);

        if j == 1 && i == 1 % set up the initial plots for each subplot
% s1,2,3,4 are the handles for the subplots
            h1 = scatter3(s1,x, y, z, 'MarkerFaceColor', [0 .75 .75],...
                'MarkerEdgeColor','k');
            h2 = scatter3(s2,x, y, z, 'MarkerFaceColor', [0 .75 .75],...
                'MarkerEdgeColor','k');
            h3 = scatter3(s3,x, y, z, 'MarkerFaceColor', [0 .75 .75],...
                'MarkerEdgeColor','k');
            h4 = scatter3(s4,x, y, z, 'MarkerFaceColor', [0 .75 .75],...
                'MarkerEdgeColor','k');
        else % update data
%                 this is probably insanely redundant
            set(h1, 'XData', x, 'YData', y, 'ZData', z);
            set(h2, 'XData', x, 'YData', y, 'ZData', z);
            set(h3, 'XData', x, 'YData', y, 'ZData', z);
            set(h4, 'XData', x, 'YData', y, 'ZData', z);
        end
    end
    frames(n) = getframe(gcf); % capture frames
    n = n + 1;
end
```

Can anyone help find what I need to change here to make it plot, instead of after every j (individual marker), after ever nth j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is, you are currently only updating the `XData`, `YData`, and `ZData` for one marker at each instant at a time. Instead you want to get rid of the inner loop and get an *array* of `x`, `y`, and `z` variables. You can then use these for the `scatter3` calls as well as to update the `XData`, `YData`, and `ZData`.

```
for i = 1:length(data)      
    %// Get XYZ coordinates for all markers at this time and reshape so X,Y,Z are rows
    xyz = reshape(markerLoc(i,:), 3, []);

    if i == 1
        %// Put these in an array so we can update them easier
        h(1) = scatter3(s1, xyz(1,:), xyz(2,:), xyz(3,:), ...
                        'MarkerFaceColor', [0 .75 .75],...
                        'MarkerEdgeColor','k');

        %// Just use copyobj to make a copy of this plot to all axes
        h(2:4) = copyobj(h(1), [s2, s3, s4]);
    else
        set(h, 'XData', xyz(1,:), 'YData', xyz(2,:), 'ZData', xyz(3,:))
    end
end
```

Comment: Wow, not only does that work,  but it looks damn good and makes my plots look exactly how I wanted them to. I knew it was something along those lines - storing all the points in one xyz array - but for whatever reason just could not wrap my mind around how exactly to get it done. Thanks a lot, man, I really appreciate it!